# Why constructors if curl braces

Tags: c#

What is a sense to create set of constructors if there is still possibility to initiate any set of fields for a class using curly braces? Never thought about that before but from my experience i could make few `constructors` to secure the way class can be constructed. Nevertheless every time curly bracets can be used which to me is something like a hack overcoming constructors. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Could you provide some code to help with the question. I don't understand what you mean by the `curly brackets` and a `constructor`

Comment: [Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors) is a method which is used to create a new instance of a type

Comment: The constructor is called even if you use the brace initializer.

Comment: When you absolutely, positively need to have certain properties set for the class to work properly (including any passed parameters), you put it in the constructor.

Answer (score 4):

If you are allowing the fields and properties to be set by the caller, yes, there is no difference. But the constructor is not only about setting fields, it holds the logic to instantiate an object.

If you want the object to be immutable and be changed only by itself, you should use `readonly` fields and read-only properties. 
Read-only properties are declared by not providing a setter, or more simply, the `set` keyword.

An example:

```
public class YourClass
{
   readonly string readonlyField;
   public int ImmutableIntProperty {get;}

   public YourClass(string field, int value)
   {
       readonlyField = field;
       ImmutableIntProperty = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: So i dont See a sense lets Say if in ten places diffrent fields have to be set isnt Just better rather than creating ten diffrent constructors to instaniate using bracets and fields i need and having 1 default constructors to put logic cause default ctor is always called

Answer (score 0):

`Constructors` are not only for object initialization, but we can also use it to inject dependencies.

For **Example:** we can inject the dependency of `Logger` class to `Constructor` to use it throughout the class.

```
public class Demo
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Demo> _logger;

        public Demo(ILogger<Demo> logger)
        {
            // Use _logger throughout the class
            _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        }

        public void Log()
        {
            // _logger.Log(message);
        }
    }
```

**NOTE:** Some dependencies are resolved by `.Net` itself, but in case of custom types we need to resolve dependency by our self. This will help to to achieve `loose coupling` between types and is extensively used in multi tier projects.